# Check if a text box starts with 92 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, alert

```
<form name="home" action="" onsubmit="return Validateform();" method="post">

<input type="text" name="receiver" />

<input type="submit" value="send" name="send" />
</form>
```

What is the javascript to alert if the textbox does not start with 92 on submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you read a JavaScript tutorial. Try [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

To answer your question, this will probably work. If you're wondering why you're getting downvoted - asking people to write your code for you is generally considered bad form, so try not to do this in future. :)

```
function Validateform(e) {
  if (document.getElementsByName('receiver')[0].value.substring(0, 2) !== "92") {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Alert");
  }
}
```